# How to handle with endpoint response in WSO2 API Manager gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am working on source code and I want to add some additional functions if requests failed. For example, If a request failed I shouldn't charge for this request.

A request failed if http status code is not 200. There is also information in response body which indicates if request failed.

So I want to know how could I handle response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [custom sequence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) with synapse (and java if you want) to read the response, and attach it to your API's out sequence.